# Android connection to MySQL - Php or Servlet?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, servlets

This is not a codefix question but please help me where possible.

I am developing an application which needs to store information in a database. This information needs to be stored off-device for security reasons (patient data).

I have explored using PHP as a bridge to the external MySQL database hosted locally via WAMP, however I have recently been informed of servlets and also of SQLite.

As I am learning these technologies under a limited time frame I need to know which to invest my time into to get the job done as easily as possible. I have no experience with any query language but I did get a simple login screen to work on Android using PHP and MySQL on WAMP using HTTP post/fetch within android.

Also, is it possible to store the information in SQLite within android and write that data to a server, which can then load the SQLite database again on re-launch?

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Does the application need to work offline? If not, you might want to consider using jQuery mobile with a PHP backend to develop a touch-optimised web app, rather than something native Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our expericence these kind of services need to work offline if possible. Both 3g and especially wifi has been unreliable in several occasions.

You do good if you save the data locally in e.g. sqlite database but be warned the data can get wiped on OS update or software update.

Also try to write your changes/additions in batches and servr updater can send all the batches that are not yet on the server. this way it's more reliable if you miss updates.

These kind of interfaces to another systems take a lot of time in testing. Consider getting a new timeframe in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will find more about Android connection to MySQL [here](http://learninformatique.blogspot.com)